# While Creating $mdToast Service, function not calling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-material, angularjs-service

Creating the custom service, in that using $mdToast.show() method to display the toast message. This service is injected in another controller and calling this service function from that controller. Able to display the toast message, but not able to call hide function on clicking on ***img*** element.

testservice.js

```
function foo(){
var toast = $mdToast.show({
position: 'top left',
template: message, // var message = '<h4> Hey Toaster </h4>'+ '<img scr="button.png" ng-click="hide()" ></img>';
hideDelay: 0)};

var hide = function(){
$mdToast.hide(toast);
}
 }
```

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, testService) {

testService.foo();
};
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling from the `hide` method in the `testService`? Post that code please. I suppose it's from the controller which manages the _template_ `message`. Is that right?

Comment: yes. in testService in message , passing html code as variable. in that img element ng-click= hide() method is calling

Comment: please add the code for both controller and service pertinent to question.

Comment: @alphapilgrim code Updated

Comment: @lealceldeiro code Updated

Comment: I guess you have not defined a controller for the toast template, so the action `hide` doesn't exist in the toast context. Is that right?

Comment: @lealceldeiro yes. if denfine controller: 'toastCtrl' toast is not displaying.

Comment: If you defined a controller for the toast template it should have been assigned when you call the `$mdToast.show` in the options parameters like this: `controller  : 'toastCtrl'`. Right? And then in that controller should be defined the `hide` action that will close the toast.

Comment: @lealceldeiro will please provide sample code to define hide action in the 'controller:' toastCtrl'' in service function

Comment: @lealceldeiro, problem solved.. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've been pretty busy today at work. I couldn't answer you quick enough.